# Text looks terrible on second display

Tags: windows-8.1, graphics-card, multiple-monitors, hdmi, amd-catalyst

I'm running Windows 8.1 and have two HDMI TVs hooked up to my PC, one I use regularly and one I've just hooked up as an extended display.

Problem is, text looks terrible on my second display! I've tried changing the settings in Catalyst Control Center, Windows Calibrate Display and even on the TV's own settings menu itself.

Any ideas why it looks so sharp and how I can fix it?

SCREENSHOTS:

Display 1 (Perfectly fine): https://www.dropbox.com/s/4s3jow1f60hai1e/2014-10-17%2022.37.36.jpg?dl=0

Display 2 (Terrible): https://www.dropbox.com/s/12vbbknq6ratz49/2014-10-17%2022.37.44.jpg?dl=0

Cheers!

Comment: Make sure you're using the proper "native" resolution on both TV's. Make sure the TV that shows "terrible" text is set to "PC mode" or something similar (in the TV's setup menu). Try switching cables to see if it could be the output and/or cable that has a defect. If none of this helps, tell us the exact make/model of the PC and TV's in order for us to try and provide a better answer. Good luck!